# R: For loop to capture data from multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I want to create some function to get the desired output. I am learning R and hence finding difficulties to create the code.

These are the sample dataframes I want to create it for larger dataset

Dataframe 1:

```
 Item   LC1    LC2   LC3
8T4121  MW92    OY01    RM11
AB7654  MW92    WK14    RM11
AB7654  MW92    WK14    RS11
```

Dataframe 2:

```
 Item   LC   custfcst
8T4121  MW92    10
8T4121  OY01    12
8T4121  RM11    10
AB7654  MW92    20
AB7654  WK14    10
AB7654  RM11    8
AB7654  RS11    21
```

Dataframe 3:

```
 Item    LC     ToLC    Rolledfcst
8T4121  MW92    OY01    22
8T4121  OY01    RM11    10
AB7654  MW92    WK14    30
AB7654  WK14    RM11    12
AB7654  WK14    RS11    10
```

Dataframe 4:

```
Item    LC      Safetystock(SS)       X
8T4121  MW92    15                   .25
8T4121  OY01    7                    .25
8T4121  RM11    5                    .25
AB7654  MW92    30                   .25
AB7654  WK14    8                    .25
AB7654  RM11    20                   .25
AB7654  RS11    15                   .25
```

Expected output:

```
 Item   LC1      Pcntg     Share       RemSS    FinalSS        Leftover
8T4121  MW92   10/(22+10)  Pcntg*SS  SS-Share   Share+X*RemSS  SS-FinalSS
8T4121  OY01   12/(10+12)  Pcntg*SS  SS-Share   Share+X*RemSS  SS-FinalSS
8T4121  RM11       NA
```

Note: Here Leftover at Item 8T4121 and LC1 should get added at SafetyStock in Dataframe 4 for same Item no then only next computation should happen at 8T4121 and OY01

Steps:
1. In Dataframe, it is lane where item is flowing from LC1-->LC2-->LC3

2. For the output, one each Item, custfcst should be taked from DF2, Rolledfcst sould be taken from DF3 to calculate the Pcntg
3. Similarly, Share, RemSS, FinalSS, Leftover should be calculated
4. After we calculate the for 1st Item then Leftover should be added to the Safety Stock for next LC for same Item
5. When we come at last LC in Dataframe 1 for a particular Item no then only SS+Leftover at previous Lc should be added. No further calculations are required.

In case of Item AB7654, aster computation at Wk 14 it should divide leftover SS equally amongst RM11 and RS11

Comment: Added the expected output

Comment: Can someone provide an solution to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `Tidyverse` solution that uses `left_join` several times to join your data frames together:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  gather(key = LC_ref, value = LC, - Item) %>%
  left_join(select(df2, -Item), by = "LC") %>%
  left_join(select(df3, -Item, -ToLC), by = "LC") %>%
  mutate(percentage = ifelse(is.na(custfcst) | is.na(Rolledfcst), NA, paste(custfcst, Rolledfcst, sep = "/")),
         percentage_numerical = 100 * custfcst / Rolledfcst) %>%
  select(Item, LC, percentage, percentage_numerical)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Item   LC    percentage percentage_numerical
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>                     <dbl>
1 8T4121 MW92  10/22                      45.5
2 8T4121 OY01  12/10                     120  
3 8T4121 RM11  NA                         NA
```